# Contour from triangulation in Python

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have a set of 2d vertices (x,y) and a set of triangles referring to the vertices' index (p1,p2,p3).

The vertices represent a closed polygon shape, however those are not in order.

When 'merging' all the triangles together, we get a the area of the desired polygon (from which we can conclude the contour).

I've manage to achieve this with the following method (multiple polygon union), however not sure about its efficiency. Any advice?

My database is 1M+ entries.

Thanks

Nb this question has been forwarded from here

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

def get_region(vertices, triangles):
    region = Polygon()

    for i, tri in enumerate(triangles):
        a = vertices[tri[0]]
        b = vertices[tri[1]]
        c = vertices[tri[2]]
        p = Polygon ([a, b, c])

        try:
            region = cascaded_union([region, p])
        except ValueError:
            print ('value error at: ', i)

    return (list(region.exterior.coords))

region = get_region(vertices, triangles)
```

[image]

Vertices:

```
[(2075, 2811),
 (1992, 2790),
 (1992, 2759),
 (3457, 2527),
 (2459, 2146),
 (3460, 2492),
 (3463, 2435),
 (3465, 2321),
 (2312, 2209),
 (1999, 2622),
 (2178, 2283),
 (2423, 2154),
 (2443, 2150),
 (1998, 2613),
 (1987, 2555),
 (2002, 2383),
 (1994, 2398),
 (1999, 2387),
 (1993, 2606),
 (1983, 2520),
 (1982, 2486),
 (2080, 2345),
 (2045, 2362),
 (1992, 2403),
 (1985, 2434),
 (2063, 2355),
 (1995, 2392),
 (3458, 2206),
 (3025, 1983),
 (3207, 1991),
 (3459, 2200),
 (3461, 2191),
 (3468, 2157),
 (3310, 1997),
 (3470, 2101),
 (3385, 2009),
 (2832, 1976),
 (2568, 2058),
 (2648, 2005),
 (2507, 2101),
 (2461, 2142),
 (2461, 2138),
 (2702, 1975),
 (2721, 1976),
 (2680, 1979),
 (2692, 1976),
 (2713, 1975),
 (2774, 1973),
 (2896, 1975),
 (3463, 2063),
 (3469, 2074),
 (3457, 2049),
 (3439, 2025),
 (3458, 2044),
 (3451, 2029),
 (3458, 2039),
 (3456, 2033),
 (3424, 2021),
 (3460, 2056),
 (3465, 2179),
 (3459, 2210),
 (3461, 2219),
 (3466, 2249),
 (3437, 2662),
 (3434, 2680),
 (3418, 2754),
 (3405, 2787),
 (1999, 2631),
 (3445, 2610),
 (3399, 2804),
 (3398, 2811),
 (1995, 2812),
 (1994, 2705),
 (3433, 2689),
 (2071, 2350),
 (1999, 2630),
 (1999, 2631)]
```

Triangles:

```
[(0, 1, 2),
 (3, 4, 5),
 (6, 4, 7),
 (8, 9, 10),
 (11, 12, 8),
 (13, 14, 10),
 (15, 16, 17),
 (14, 13, 18),
 (19, 20, 21),
 (22, 16, 15),
 (23, 16, 22),
 (23, 22, 24),
 (25, 20, 24),
 (26, 17, 16),
 (14, 19, 21),
 (14, 21, 10),
 (13, 10, 9),
 (12, 4, 8),
 (27, 28, 29),
 (30, 29, 31),
 (32, 33, 34),
 (33, 35, 34),
 (36, 37, 38),
 (39, 4, 40),
 (39, 40, 41),
 (42, 43, 44),
 (43, 38, 44),
 (44, 45, 42),
 (43, 42, 46),
 (47, 38, 43),
 (36, 38, 47),
 (48, 37, 36),
 (39, 37, 48),
 (39, 48, 28),
 (39, 28, 4),
 (34, 49, 50),
 (51, 52, 53),
 (52, 54, 55),
 (54, 56, 55),
 (52, 55, 53),
 (57, 52, 51),
 (57, 51, 35),
 (51, 58, 35),
 (58, 49, 35),
 (35, 49, 34),
 (29, 33, 32),
 (29, 32, 59),
 (29, 59, 31),
 (27, 29, 30),
 (60, 28, 27),
 (61, 28, 60),
 (62, 28, 61),
 (7, 28, 62),
 (4, 28, 7),
 (5, 4, 6),
 (0, 8, 63),
 (9, 8, 0),
 (63, 64, 0),
 (65, 66, 0),
 (9, 0, 67),
 (68, 63, 8),
 (69, 0, 66),
 (0, 69, 70),
 (0, 71, 1),
 (72, 0, 2),
 (65, 0, 73),
 (73, 0, 64),
 (3, 68, 4),
 (4, 68, 8),
 (74, 21, 25),
 (22, 25, 24),
 (21, 20, 25),
 (9, 67, 75),
 (67, 76, 75),
 (72, 67, 0)]
```

Comment: Your `triangles[72]` cannot be right, it is not a triangle. The vertices work out to be `[(1999, 2622), (1999, 2631), (1999, 2630)]`. Maybe an error from dropping a float part?

Comment: (@Graipher: that looks a *degenerate* triangle which shouldn't be produced during a triangulation.)

Comment: @greybeard: Maybe so. I thought it could come from original vertices being `(1999.2, ...), (1999.3, ...), (1999.4, ...)` and then truncating to integers for some reason. In any case the function in the OP stumbles over this as well, but continues, mine raises an exception as it probably should.

Comment: I did not conclude the data myself but work with an existing database ('http://opensurfaces.cs.cornell.edu/') and, yes there are some errors in the data which is why i introduced the try/except part (apologies, should have mentioned this). The errors are pretty rare though and generally have no effect on the desired final outcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cascaded_union` function can take more than one object, so you should be able to do:

```
from shapely.geometry import Polygon, MultiPolygon
from shapely.ops import cascaded_union

def get_region(vertices, triangles):
    regions = MultiPolygon([Polygon([vertices[i] for i in triangle])
                            for triangle in triangles])
    return list(cascaded_union(regions).exterior.coords)
```

When deleting `triangle[72]` from your example, which is not really a triangle and the reason for your `try...except ValueError`, this gives the same area for this function and yours, `1060307.0`.

If you cannot delete those zero-size triangles manually, you can do it programmatically as well:

```
def get_region(vertices, triangles):
    polygons = (Polygon([vertices[i] for i in triangle])
                for triangle in triangles)
    regions = MultiPolygon([p for p in polygons if p.area > 0])
    return list(cascaded_union(regions).exterior.coords)
```

I would leave getting the points of the exterior to the caller, or another function, but I left it here in order to not change the interface.

Note that [`cascaded_union` may be superseded by `unary_union`](https://shapely.readthedocs.io/en/stable/manual.html#shapely.ops.cascaded_union), depending on the version you are using.

I am not sure why you use the datastructure you have. It would be easier to directly store the vertices for each triangle as a three-tuple, so that you could just do:

```
def get_region(triangles):
    polygons = (Polygon(triangle) for triangle in triangles)
    regions = MultiPolygon([p for p in polygons if p.area > 0])
    return list(cascaded_union(regions).exterior.coords)
```